# unregisterForRemoteNotifications still shows "Allow Notifications" as on in Settings

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm creating a settings page which allows the user to turn push notifications on and off.  Here's my question.  If the user Allows Push Notifications at the initial system prompt then later changes their mind and turns the UISwitch to No, I have my off switch action to be:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];

But if you go to the settings app on the phone Allow Notifications is still set to On.  I know unregistering them invalidated the token so they won't get any more notifications.  But I think they will be confused if the settings app still says they are Allowing Notifications. Do I still need to redirect the user out of the app to settings app to turn OFF remote notifications?  Or is there some code I can add that will change Allow Notifications to Off in the Settings app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't change setting app from your app. You have to manually disable it from setting app. as mentioned in another answer you can prompt message to permanently disable (please do it through the settings app).

Second thing if you want to make your server know that don't send notification to this device then
You can do something like this,

if you want to do Inside the app then use one identifier and send it to server according push notification enable and disable button. So, your server side coding use this identifier and work according to that. Like identifier is say it's enable than your server will send notification otherwise not.

You can check that user set `enable` or `disable`  `Push Notifications` using following code.

Enable or Disable Iphone Push Notifications

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) 
 // Yes it is..
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/unregisterForRemoteNotifications)

> You should call this method in rare circumstances only, such as when a
>   new version of the app removes support for all types of remote
>   notifications. Users can temporarily prevent apps from receiving
>   remote notifications through the Notifications section of the Settings
>   app. Apps unregistered through this method can always re-register.

I believe what it does is only unregister but do not disable the option of the user settings which the app requested. specially the point **Apps unregistered through this method can always re-register**

This probably specifies that if you call the register notification method again, user wont be prompted to grant permission as it has already been done before.

I believe you should add a detail sub label to the section of the cell in your app settings screen specifying that the

> app will stop receiving notifications, to permanently disable (please
>   do it through the settings app).

Comment: Can i change Push notification register settings after unregistering and then while registering with different authorization options?

I tried it but it seems like its able to register automatically but its not taking new authorization options.

Any suggestions how we can change authorization options in run time?